# selecting multiple choices from selectizeInput and plotting multiple lines for each choice in r

Tags: r, plot, shiny, plotly

I'm working on a simple line graph in r. for now I can use two selectizeInputs in the UI part to choose a season and a team, each selectizeInput has an ID that is used in the server part in a select statement, anyway I want to adjust the code so that I can select multiple seasons and multiple teams and when that happens I want to plot multiple lines on the graph for each team and season. My question is what should I change in the UI part and what should I change in the server part?
thanks very much for any help!

this is UI part

```
libraries("plotly","ggplot2","plotrix")

ui <- fluidPage(
fluidRow(
column ( width = 3,

         h4(span(tagList(icon("filter")), "Select season")),
         selectizeInput('season', "", choices = shots$SeasonNr, selected = TRUE, multiple = TRUE),
         br(),


         h4(span(tagList(icon("filter")), "Select team")),
         selectizeInput('team', "", choices = shots$TeamName, selected = TRUE, multiple = TRUE),
         br()
)),


 plotlyOutput("pos1")

)
```

this is my server part

```
server <- function(input,output, session){
  observeEvent(c(input$team), {

team1 <- input$team
Season1 <- input$season

tp <- sqldf(sprintf("select TeamName,  Training_ID, SeasonNr, Position, ShotAverage from shots where TeamName is '%s'", team1,"AND SeasonNr is '%s'", Season1))
dfNew<- aggregate(ShotAverage ~ tp$TeamName  +tp$Position, data=tp, FUN=mean)
#creates empty dataframe
dfF <- data.frame()
#bind
dfF <- rbind(dfF, dfNew)
colnames(dfF) <- c("Team Name", "Position", "Average")
 # render the plot
 output$pos1 <-renderPlotly({ 
   plot_ly(x = ~dfF$Position, y = ~dfF$Average, type = 'scatter', mode = 'bar')%>%
     layout(title = 'Seasonal team statistics', xaxis = list(title = "Position"),yaxis = list(title = "Average")) 
 })
 })}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: could you please supply parts of your data `shots` preferbly with `dput`

Answer (score 0):

untill you have supported us with your data i made an similar example with another dataset from `ggplot2`

```
library("plotly","ggplot2","plotrix")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column ( width = 3,

             h4(span(tagList(icon("filter")), "Select season")),
             selectizeInput('season', "", choices = txhousing$year %>% unique(),selected = TRUE,  multiple = TRUE),
             br(),


             h4(span(tagList(icon("filter")), "Select city")),
             selectizeInput('city', "", choices = txhousing$city %>% unique(), selected = TRUE, multiple = TRUE),
             br()
    )),


  plotlyOutput("pos1")

)
server <- function(input,output, session){
  dta <- reactive({

    req(input$city,input$season)

    txhousing %>% 
      select(city,year,month,median) %>% 
      filter(city %in% input$city, year %in% input$season) %>% 
      group_by(city,month) %>% 
      summarise(median = mean(median))
  })
  output$pos1 <-renderPlotly({ 
    plot_ly(data = dta(),x = ~month, y = ~median,type = "area",color = ~city) %>%
      layout(title = 'Seasonal team statistics', xaxis = list(title = "Month"),yaxis = list(title = "Average")) 
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

please not that I have separated your code into one reactive and a render statement. This is a better design for shiny then putting everything within an observer statment

Hope this helps!!